# Is (size_t)0 a good practice in C or not?

Tags: c, casting, coding-style

I've seen the following in C code and it seems strange to me:

```
myType GetStuff(size_t *iSize) {
    *iSize = (size_t)0;    
    size_t h = 0;       
    *iSize += h;
}
```

Everything works without the cast as well: `*iSize = 0;`.

Is there any need for the `(size_t)` cast or is it superfluous?

Comment: Most probably this is a fix for a compiler warning, if not - it cold be removed

Comment: Maybe it's something about the pointer I don't see here?

Comment: Why `*iSize = 0` would give a warning and not `h = 0`, since `*iSize` and `h` are of the same type... (in other words: if `*iSize = 0` needs a cast, `h = 0`should have a cast as well).

Comment: You shouldn't change the question like that, the answers and comments will not reflect the question.

Comment: True, I've seen after @Lundin's answer that I've simplified the code too much.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, I'm all for improving the questions, but before the edit the variables were not initialized, that lead to a deleted answer from [Lundin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584518/lundin) that was all about that.

Comment: @anastaciu: I have seen the question history, and my comment stands. The intended question was stated **explicitly**. Answers should have focused on the question that was asked. Statements about other aspects of the code in the question ought to be relegated to minor status, such as supplementary notes. And, as I wrote, it is not uncommon for people to display a declaration merely to show the type of an object, not to represent actual code. Good or bad, this is seen not uncommonly, so experienced participants ought to recognize it and not jump on a poster because of it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The original code could very well have been a bug caused by someone mixing up `*iSize = (size_t)0;` and `iSize = (size_t*)0;`. Only the location of the `*` is different and the latter is perfectly valid code for assigning a null pointer to an uninitialized pointer variable.

Comment: Though I decided to edit out a part of my answer that no longer makes sense, I have to recognize that the focus of the question was not changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any need in (size_t) cast or its superfluous?

Arithmetic types convert implicitly. You don't need a cast. That said, the cast improves the readability of the code and might avoid some warnings from some compilers.

Comment: If it's just the cast issue, then being explicit is good. It is sloppy to allow implicit conversions from signed to unsigned. It's common to have compilers and static analysers set to warn against such conversions, so the cast makes sense.

Comment: I see your point, from the readbility perspective is easier to detect.